# Trying to open a .vbs file in .bat but it asks for a program to open it with

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

So im trying to open a .vbs file with a .bat file (the vbs file is in the same folder as the bat file)

```
start %~dp0 req.vbs
```

but when i run the batch i get this when it tries to open reg.vbs
[image here](http://gyazo.com/90d2c623a5fa1722fcb3c5da9342fb4d)

would not let me add a gyazo image)

i dont know how to get it to open the vbs file properly

Comment: Looking your image I see the _File: Gage_ specification there. Where the `Gage` name comes from? FYI: in my OS another `Open with` dialogue appears so I can't reproduce your issue satisfactorily.

Comment: I see a space in `start %~dp0 req.vbs` between `%~dp0` and `req.vbs`. Try `start %~dp0req.vbs` or `start "" "%~dp0req.vbs"`

Comment: ware able to open the vbs file?

Answer (score 1):

try with (output will be in the console)

```
cscript /nologo /e:vbscript req.vbs
```

or (output will be with annoying pop-ups)

```
wscript /e:vbscript req.vbs
```

Comment: this worked for me, except you made the file reQ were the actual file was reG so i had to midfie your code a bit. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check the `%PATHEXT%` system environment variable: `set PATHEXT` command should return a list of recognized *executable* file extensions and should contain the `.VBS`, for instance as follows:

```
==>set pathext
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
```

Check file association using [`assoc`](http://ss64.com/nt/assoc.html) and [`ftype`](http://ss64.com/nt/ftype.html) commands as follows:

```
==>assoc .vbs
.vbs=VBSFile

==>ftype VBSFile
VBSFile="%SystemRoot%\System32\WScript.exe" "%1" %*
```

To [re-establish the link](http://ss64.com/nt/ftype.html) between the `.vbs` FileType and an executable program (note that `cmd` should be *run as administrator* and the operating sequence matters):

```
ftype VBSFile="%SystemRoot%\System32\WScript.exe" "%1" %*
assoc .vbs=VBSFile
```

or

```
ftype VBSFile="%SystemRoot%\System32\CScript.exe" "%1" %*
assoc .vbs=VBSFile
```

If you are using above commands **from a batch script** then double percent signs in `"%%1"` and `%%*` as follows:

```
ftype VBSFile="%SystemRoot%\System32\WScript.exe" "%%1" %%*
assoc .vbs=VBSFile
```

or

```
ftype VBSFile="%SystemRoot%\System32\CScript.exe" "%%1" %%*
assoc .vbs=VBSFile
```

Comment: i hardly understood a word you just said :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PUSHD` to switch to the current directory before running the command.

```
PUSHD %~dp0
req.vbs
POPD
```

Comment: `start /wait "" cmd /c` is not required. `cscript.exe` works fine by itself.